# React-Native-Vector-Icons error on build android

Tags: icons, react-native

[image]

I already installed it, but it still error

Comment: you will find this error with React-Native 0.52.0, but not with 0.49.0.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
rm ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json
```

restart packager, and it works.